# jquery validate wont validate if file with multiple attribute is empty

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i have a form to accept text information and also a file input with multiple attribute, everything works fine until i noticed it wont work if files field is empty, the file upload should be optional, but the challenge is : if the file input is empty, jquery validate wont work. but whenever it has a content then, jquery validate would work. 
what i want to acheive is: i need it to validate the form but the multiple file input field should be optional, but when files are selected, it should validate them.
i use jquery and laravel.
here is my code.
my html:

```
<form id="questionForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @csrf
 <div class="form-inputs clearfix">
<p>
   <label class="required">Question Title<span>*</span></label>
   <input type="text" id="question-title" name="title">                                                
   <span class="form-description">Please choose an appropriate title for the question to answer it even easier .</span>
 </p>                                            
<div class="clearfix"></div>
 <p>
   <label>Attachment</label>
           <div class="fileinputs">
                <input type="file" class="file" name="images[]" id="photo" multiple style=""/>
          <div class="fakefile">
   <button type="button" class="button small margin_0" id="fake_btn">Select file</button>
    <span><i class="icon-arrow-up"></i>Browse</span>
    </div>
</div>
</p>
<div id="form-textarea">
   <p>
    <label class="required">Details<span>*</span></label>
    <textarea id="question-details" name="question" aria-required="true" cols="58" rows="8"></textarea>
  <span class="form-description">Type the description thoroughly and in detail .</span>
   </p>
</div>
 <center><span><img src="../../svg/loader.gif" style="width:30px;height:30px;" id="loader-icon"/></span></center>
<div class="alert-message success">
  <i class="icon-ok"></i>
 <p><span>success</span><br>
 </p>
  </div>
 <p class="form-submit">
     <button id="publish-question" class="button color small submit">Publish Your Question</button>
 </p>
</form>
```

here is what i have in my jquery.

as suggested by sparky, here is my code for maxFileSize and maxFilesToSelect

```
$.validator.addMethod('filesize', function (value, element, param) {
        return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param)
        }, 'File size must be less than {0}');

        $.validator.addMethod('maxFileSize', function (value, element, param) {
        var lg = element.files.length;
        var items = element.files;
        var fileSize = 0;
        if (lg > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < lg; i++) {
                fileSize = fileSize+items[i].size; // get file size
            }
            if(fileSize > param) {
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }
        if(element.files[0].size <= param){
            return true;
        }
        }, 'Each file should be less or equal to 2MB');
```

anyway this is not the problem because this works well

```
$("#questionForm").validate({
            rules: {
                title: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10,
                    maxlength: 100
                },
                question: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 20,
                },
                'images[]': {
                    extension: "jpg,jpeg,png",
                    maxFileSize: 2097152,//i have this setup
                    maxFilesToSelect : 4,//this works aswell
                }
            },
            messages: {
                title: {
                    required: 'Please enter a title for this Question.',
                    minlength: 'minimum title lenght must be above 10 characters',
                    maxlength: 'exceeded the allow number of characters for title field'
                },
                question: {
                    required: 'Please enter a description for this Question.',
                    minlength: 'minimum body lenght must be above 20 characters'
                }
            },
            submitHandler:function(form){
                $('#publish-question').html('Sending..');
                $('#publish-question').attr('disabled','disabled');
                $('.alert-success').hide();
                $('#loader-icon').fadeIn();
                var oData = new FormData(form);
                $.ajax({
                    async: true,
                    url: "/save",
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: oData ,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success:function(data){
                        //do something
                     }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
```

is there way to do something like

```
required:false //just to make it validate only when field has file.
```

this is what i have in my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request){
        $attribute = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'title' => 'required|min:10',
            'question' => 'required|min:20',
            'images.*' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:2048'
        ]
        );
}
```

thanks in anticipation.

Comment: If you get rid of `required: true` then it should be optional. How does this make jquery validate fail?

Comment: Does it prevent it from validating the other fields? Or does it make it ignore the other options for the `images[]` input?

Comment: the required: true is not set , jquery validate doesnt work, if the ```required: true ``` is not there ...it doesnt validate other field

Comment: `maxFileSize` and `maxFilesToSelect` are not rules that are built into this plugin.  If these are custom rule that you have created, then show us these functions.

Comment: Based on [this issue posted on GitHub about the `multiple` attribute](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/issues/1722), the plugin was never designed to handle it.  I suggest you post this on the author's GitHub page as a feature request.